# Where to explore Emacs-Lisp APIs?

Tags: help

Is there a web app for Emacs-Lisp API searching with nice description, links, examples, etc?
Something like http://apidock.com/ for Ruby, or http://en.cppreference.com/w/ for C++, etc.

Comment: I know this one: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html#Top but it's usually much easier to look up the signature / help inside Emacs itself (via `M-x apropos`, `C-h f` and similar aids).

Comment: `C-h i`, `C-h f` and `C-h S` are your best friends. Also consider asking on the mailing list.

Answer (score 3):

**No, there isn't anything as nice as those online docs.**

That being said, your Emacs is the best source of information. The online Emacs reference only applies to the latest released version of Emacs, so some of it may not apply to your version.

I highly recommend the [`helm-apropos`](https://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#orgheadline17) command from the [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) package, which allows for incremental completion of function, command, variable, and face names. I find it invaluable for exploring a new Emacs package.

Also consider the `apropos-documentation` command, which allows you to search inside docstrings.

As for external documentation, take a look at Artur Malabarba's [Emacs Online Documentation](http://doc.endlessparentheses.com/app.html) (also available as an Android app!).